# React useState set state method not trigering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, single-page-application, use-state

I am facing quite a specific problem with React useState. I am declaring new state using useState hook like that:

```
const [dialogData, setDialogData] = useState(null);
```

When I set new state via `setDialogData(newState)` everything works just fine until any `history.push()` is called. After that when I try to set state with `setDialogData` method logic is ignored and not triggered. For example for such code snippet:

```
setDialogData((prev) => { 
    console.log('setDialogData entered');
    return newState;
}
```

"setDialogData entered" will not be printed.

I'm not sure if this matters, but in my case, `setDialogData` is called in the callback method that is registered as a signalR received message handler.

**EDIT**
This is the actual code:

```
const handleOperationRequested = (response) => {
        setDialogData((prev) => {
            console.log('setDialogData entered');
            
            return {
                isOpen: true,
                id: response.id,
                name: response.name
            };
        });   
    };
```

`handleOperationRequested` is registered as a message handler in signalR:

```
this.hubConnection.on('operationRequested', (res) => handleOperationRequested(res));
```

This is all code I am able to present, because of company privacy policy, but also this is everything from the code that is relevant to that case. As I mentioned, this is working until `history.push()` from `react-router-dom` is called. After that "setDialogData entered" is no longer printed, as well as state is not updated.

Comment: Please show more code so we can better understand what actually is happening.

Comment: check if your component is being unmounted because of the `history.push`

Comment: @thedude component is unmounted on exiting and mounted on entering